# How do I use a function in a view to return only distinct union of rows?

Tags: function, sql-server-2012, dataset, view, radgrid

I am trying to do a view to reference on a webpage using RadGrid control. I need to get a subset of all records in my projects table by the last entered Changedate in the Changes table per unique projectid with the Status from the Status table along with the details of the project. The ProjectId & StatusID are in the Changes table as foreign Keys.

This is my view.

```
CREATE VIEW [dbo].[Project-by_View]
AS
SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT
    dbo.Projects.Id,
    dbo.Projects.ProjectName,
    dbo.Department.Name,
    dbo.Designer.FName + ' ' + dbo.Designer.LName AS Designer,
    dbo.Changes.ChangeDate,
    dbo.Projects.DueDate,
    dbo.Projects.Instructions,
    dbo.Status.Description
FROM  dbo.Projects
INNER JOIN dbo.Department
   ON dbo.Department.ID = dbo.Projects.DeptID
INNER JOIN dbo.Designer 
   ON dbo.Designer.Id = dbo.Projects.DesignerID
INNER JOIN dbo.Changes
   ON dbo.Changes.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ID 
INNER JOIN dbo.Status
   ON dbo.Changes.StatusID = dbo.Status.Id
WHERE EXIST (SELECT * 
             FROM GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds(0))
ORDER BY dbo.Projects.ID DESC

GO
```

and my function

```
USE [FIDO_DEV]
GO
/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds]
Script Date: 9/14/2015 4:31:22 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON 
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author, Geoffrey Stephens>
-- Create date: <Create Date, 09/14/20115>
-- Description: <Description, table of the Last Change Date for each Project>
-- =============================================
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds]
(
@ProjectID int
)
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN
(
Select ProjectID, StatusID, ChangeDate from (
Select
    ProjectID, StatusID, ChangeDate,
    row_number() over(partition by ProjectID order by ChangeDate desc) as rn
from
    Changes
) t
where t.rn = 1)

GO
```

The function works and the View work separately, but in conjunction I still get the full data set returned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This chunk looks suspicious:

```
WHERE EXIST (SELECT * 
             FROM GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds(0))
```

Should it not look more like:

```
WHERE EXIST (SELECT * 
             FROM GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds(Projects.Id))
```

I haven't looked any deeper, that just jumped out at me.

---

Try something like this (reformatted to my preferred style)

```
SELECT          Projects.Id, 
                dbo.Projects.ProjectName, 
                dbo.Department.Name, 
                dbo.Designer.FName + ' ' + dbo.Designer.LName AS Designer, 
                dbo.Changes.ChangeDate, 
                dbo.Projects.DueDate, 
                dbo.Projects.Instructions, 
                dbo.Status.Description

FROM (          SELECT          ProjectID, 
                                StatusID, 
                                ChangeDate 

                FROM (          FROM            ProjectID, 
                                                StatusID, 
                                                ChangeDate,
                                                row_number() OVER (PARTITION BY ProjectID ORDER BY ChangeDate DESC) as rn
                                FROM            Changes) t
                WHERE           t.rn = 1)) AS Selection

INNER JOIN      dbo.Projects
    ON          dbo.Projects.ID = Selection.ProjectID 

INNER JOIN      dbo.Designer 
    ON          dbo.Designer.Id = dbo.Projects.DesignerID 

INNER JOIN      dbo.Department
    ON          dbo.Department.ID = dbo.Projects.DeptID 

INNER JOIN      dbo.Changes 
    ON          dbo.Changes.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ID

INNER JOIN      dbo.Status
    ON          dbo.Changes.StatusID = dbo.Status.Id

WHERE           Selection.StatusID = dbo.Changes.StatusID 

ORDER BY        dbo.Projects.ID DESC
```

Comment: I am not passing a Project.ID to the function, so that errors out saying it could not be bound.I was thinking that maybe I need to start with the return dataset from the function, and then do my joins, b

Comment: Order by doesn't work unless you use TOP or something else in a view.

Comment: You shouldn't really be using ORDER BY inside a view.  According to my understanding of things, it's considered better practice to do the ordering outside.  ie, SELECT * FROM SomeView ORDER BY SomeColulmn ASC

Answer (score 0):

I reordered the Selects, so that I start with the Distinct project.ID and then do the joins. Then did the where on the Status.ID to get the latest distinct record set.

```
Select TOP 100 PERCENT Projects.Id, dbo.Projects.ProjectName, dbo.Department.Name, dbo.Designer.FName + ' ' + dbo.Designer.LName AS Designer, dbo.Changes.ChangeDate, dbo.Projects.DueDate, dbo.Projects.Instructions, dbo.Status.Description

From GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds(0) INNER JOIN
dbo.Projects ON dbo.Projects.ID = dbo.GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds.ProjectID INNER JOIN
dbo.Designer ON dbo.Designer.Id = dbo.Projects.DesignerID INNER JOIN
dbo.Department ON dbo.Department.ID = dbo.Projects.DeptID INNER JOIN
dbo.Changes ON dbo.Changes.ProjectID = dbo.Projects.ID INNER JOIN
dbo.Status ON dbo.Changes.StatusID = dbo.Status.Id

Where dbo.GetAllLastChangeDatebyProjectIds.StatusID = dbo.Changes.StatusID 

ORDER BY dbo.Projects.ID DESC
```

Comment: It seems a bit overkill to have that function, and what you're using it for doesn't really align very well with my interpretation of what SQL functions are designed to be used for.  Check out my edit in my previous answer, it may be more appropriate for your needs.